# Power M query syntax to get the value for a named cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I am still learning about Power Query and Power M and I'm trying to get the value of a specific "named" cell in Excel and use this in Power M.  It is just a single cell and

[image: weekone]

`=Record.Field(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="weekone"]}[Content]{0},Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="weekone"]}[Content]{0})`

Maybe I am not understanding the syntax of how to reach information in a particular field correctly, or I am getting mixed up on how to use the Record.Field() function.

Any help or guidance that can be provided would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Record.Field gives the value of a field in a record.
It takes the record as the first argument and the name of the field as the second argument.

In a step by step approach it will be clearer:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="weekone"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type date}}),
    FirstRecord = #"Changed Type"{0},
    RecordValue = Record.Field(FirstRecord,"Column1")
in
    RecordValue
```

Or, in 1 line:

```
= DateTime.Date(Record.Field(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="weekone"]}[Content]{0},"Column1"))
```

This would be an alternative:

```
= DateTime.Date(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="weekone"]}[Content]{0}[Column1])
```

My preference would be:

```
= DateTime.Date(Table.FirstValue(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="weekone"]}[Content]))
```

Comment: Thanks so much @MarcelBeug - I used your preferred one line option and it worked perfectly!  :)